# Quoted each Array Value

Tags: php

I have a PHP array as given below. I need `customkey` array's each value to be double quoted.

The array currently looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [test] => Array
        (
            [enrolId] => 
            [custom] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5:5:1-5BPOMK,5:6:Cutom Product1,5:4:Reports Test
                )

            [query] => 
        )

)
```

The output should be:

```
Array
(
    [test] => Array
        (
            [enrolId] => 
            [custom] => Array
                (
                    [0] => "5:5:1-5BPOMK","5:6:Cutom Product1","5:4:Reports Test"
                )

            [query] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: What you've tried so far? Please update your question with your code

Comment: @NarendrasinghSisodia  I have velow sting.
 $data = 5:5:1-5BPOMK,5:6:Cutom Product1,5:4:Reports Test...
i need each value should be double quote and output should be
"5:5:1-5BPOMK","5:6:Cutom Product1","5:4:Reports Test"
i tried to explode with comma but its not working for me

Comment: Try this [Demo](https://3v4l.org/Zc4lK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below code:

```
$data['test']['custom'][0] = '5:5:1-5BPOMK,5:6:Cutom Product1,5:4:Reports Test';
$data['test']['custom'][0] = '"'.implode('","', explode(",", $data['test']['custom'][0])).'"';
```

It will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try like this way with [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
<?php
function quoted_string($n)
{
    return '"'.$n.'"';
}

$data = '5:5:1-5BPOMK,5:6:Cutom Product1,5:4:Reports Test';
$array = explode(',',$data);
$expected = array_map("quoted_string", $array);
echo implode(',',$expected);

?>
```

**Output:**

```
"5:5:1-5BPOMK","5:6:Cutom Product1","5:4:Reports Test"
```

**DEMO** : https://3v4l.org/MdnJS

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple possibilities for string escaping and containing double quotes inside it: 1. The simple way - use single quotes:

```
array(
    'test' => array(
        'errolId' => null,
        'custom' => array(
            0 => '"5:5:1-5BPOMK","5:6:Cutom Product1","5:4:Reports Test"'
        )
    )
);
```

2. Or more unreadable way - escape it:

```
array(
    'test' => array(
        'errolId' => null,
        'custom' => array(
            0 => "\"5:5:1-5BPOMK\",\"5:6:Cutom Product1\",\"5:4:Reports Test\""
        )
    )
);
```

3. Use the nowdoc operator:

```
array(
    'test' => array(
        'errolId' => null,
        'custom' => array(
            0 => <<<'TEXT'
"5:5:1-5BPOMK","5:6:Cutom Product1","5:4:Reports Test"
TEXT
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough, so this only works for the example.

```
$str = '5:5:1-5BPOMK,5:6:Cutom Product1,5:4:Reports Test';
$str = '"' . str_replace(',', '","', $str) . '"';
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that your given array is declared as `$array`.

To assign this value `"5:5:1-5BPOMK","5:6:Cutom Product1","5:4:Reports Test"` to `$array['test']['custom'][0]`, add this statement after your `$array` declaration:

```
$array['test']['custom'][0] = '"' . str_replace(',', '","', $array[test][custom][0]) . '"';
```

If you want to replace all children of `$array['test']['custom']`, put the statement inside a for loop like:

```
foreach($array['test']['custom'] as $c) {
  c = '"' . str_replace(',', '","', $c) . '"';
}
```